# remove image from tableViewCell created programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, cell

I would like to move an imageView contained on a cell and it works but creating a new image at new position keeping old image (then two are shown). How could I remove old one?? used code:

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:(@"%@", showIconName)];
UIImageView *imageViewToPutInCell = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellImage];

imageViewToPutInCell.frame = CGRectMake(iconPos, 7, cellImage.size.width, cellImage.size.height); 
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageViewToPutInCell];
```

every time that I reload tableView, it creates a new overlapped image.

[cell.contentView removeFromSuperview]; used before, removes it but then new image is not created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Without subclassing, you could set the tag on your imageViewToPutInCell, then later on, use -[UIView viewWithTag:] to find and remove the view:

```
int            imageViewTag = 1234;

[[cell.contentView viewWithTag: imageViewTag] removeFromSuperview];
imageViewToPutInCell.tag = imageViewTag;
...
```

Comment: it is working using first suggested option! great, thank you Ben!!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben. It worked for me too. I was in search for a solution since a day now. Thanks a lot!!!