# UITableViewCell : UIImageView in ContentView overlaps images in iPhone SDK.

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

In my iPhone app,  I am using a tableView and have added the imageView as ContentView in my tableViewcell.

At the click of button I am changing the tableView Contents. So every time I click a button it should show the corresponding image in tableViewCell.

**Problem:**

Suppose I am loading images 1.png, 2.png and 3.png in tableView on click of button A, B and C respectively.

Now let us consider that initially I clicked button A and 1.png appears. Now when I click the button B then 2.png appears but 1.png also **remains in background**. So basically it overlaps the tableViewCell with a new image.

**Troubleshooting I already have done:**

1) I tried releasing imageView and setting imageView.image = nil;

2) I tried reloading the table and empty out table before each button click.

3) Even I tried putting the whole code in **if(cell==nil)** clause of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: try using clean build and clean all targets. I was also getting kind of a same problem

Comment: Please show the code that you have put in (cell == nil) block.

Comment: As per the accepted answer, this is a duplicate of: [remove image from tableViewCell created programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617543/remove-image-from-tableviewcell-created-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer and I am really thankful to Ben Gottlieb:

[remove image from tableViewCell created programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617543/remove-image-from-tableviewcell-created-programatically/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cell's contentView?

```
for(UIView* subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
   [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Oh you were very close to answer what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use three different imageViews then try to imgView1.hidden=FALSE;imgView.hidden=TRUE;imgView3.hidden=TRUE on button1 click event.
same way for buttton2 and button3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have set the image in the (cell==nil) block. If yes please comment that out.

Do it like:

```
if(cell ==nil){
//add image view here.
}

UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ImgViewTag];
if(condition)
   imgView.image = someImage;
else
   imgView.image = nil;
```

Comment: @PARTH Its great that you have got the answer. But if you need to change the image of imageview each time you reload the table, then removing and adding the imageview each time you need is not a great approach. You should only change the image of it else your table will not scroll smoothly. This is only my suggestion, may be you are doing something entirely different and removing the imageview suits you in your case.

Comment: I am not statically assigning images. I am taking it from database and I am reloading the tableview but images used to overlap previously even after reloading the tableview. Thanks for the suggestion though  :)